# Launching multilpe infinite python processes from one Python file

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, multiprocessing

Let's say I have three modules:

mod1
mod2
mod3

where each of them runs infinitely long as soon as mod.launch() is called.

What are some elegant ways to launch all these infinite loops at once, without waiting for one to finish before calling the other?

Let's say I'd have a kind of launcher.py, where I'd try to:

```
import mod1
import mod2
import mod3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mod1.launch()
    mod2.launch()
    mod3.launch()
```

This obviously doesn't work, as It will wait for mod1.launch() to finish before launching mod2.launch().

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to execute multiple functions in parallel, you can use either the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) library, or [concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html). ProcessPoolExecutor uses multiprocessing internally, but has a simpler interface.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nature of the work being done in each task, the answer varies.

If each task is mostly or all IO-bound, I would recommend multithreading.

If each task is CPU-bound, I would recommend multiprocessing (due to the GIL in python).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module to run each module on a separate thread, but within the same process:

```
import threading
import mod1
import mod2
import mod3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # make a list of all modules we want to run, for convenience
    mods = [mod1, mod2, mod3] 
    # Prepare a thread for each module to run the `launch()` method
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=mod.launch) for mod in mods]
    # run all threads
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    # wait for all threads to finish
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

The [`multiprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module performs a very similar set of tasks and has a very similar API, but uses separate processes instead of threads, so you can use that too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [Ray](https://github.com/ray-project/ray), which is a library for parallel and distributed Python. It has some advantages over the standard threading and multiprocessing libraries.

- The same code will run on a single machine or on multiple machines.
- You can parallelize both functions and classes.
- Objects are shared efficiently between tasks using shared memory.

To provide a simple runnable example, I'll use functions and classes instead of modules, but you can always wrap the module in a function or class.

Approach 1: Parallel **functions** using **tasks**.

```
import ray
import time

ray.init()

@ray.remote
def mod1():
    time.sleep(3)

@ray.remote
def mod2():
    time.sleep(3)

@ray.remote
def mod3():
    time.sleep(3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start the tasks. These will run in parallel.
    result_id1 = mod1.remote()
    result_id2 = mod2.remote()
    result_id3 = mod3.remote()

    # Don't exit the interpreter before the tasks have finished.
    ray.get([result_id1, result_id2, result_id3])
```

Approach 2: Parallel **classes** using **actors**.

```
import ray
import time

# Don't run this again if you've already run it.
ray.init()

@ray.remote
class Mod1(object):
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(3)

@ray.remote
class Mod2(object):
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(3)

@ray.remote
class Mod3(object):
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create 3 actors.
    mod1 = Mod1.remote()
    mod2 = Mod2.remote()
    mod3 = Mod3.remote()

    # Start the methods, these will run in parallel.
    result_id1 = mod1.run.remote()
    result_id2 = mod2.run.remote()
    result_id3 = mod3.run.remote()

    # Don't exit the interpreter before the tasks have finished.
    ray.get([result_id1, result_id2, result_id3])
```

You can see the [Ray documentation](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).